# Find number of sublists in list of many lists

Tags: python, decorator, sublist

I've got a little stuck on something on a project I'm coding and would really appreciate some help... I think it's an interesting problem too :-)

I'm trying to format coordinates that come like the below from geojson (I've shortened to paste it here as they are very long).

```
[[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]
```

I need them to end up looking like this:

```
“54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:54.722713302903806,-1.24192061729046:54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.7271584144655,-1.270237428346303:54.72608036652354,-1.268210325997062,”
```

Currently I've got this working with the below code where the variable poly is first assigned to a block of co-ordinates like the first one posted above.

```
def threetimes(func):
    """Executes the function on its own output two times."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_three_times(*args, **kwargs):
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        value2 = func(value)
        value3 = func(value2)
        return value3
    return wrapper_three_times

def swap_pairs(poly):
    """
    Turns a list like this [1, 2, 3, 4] into [2, 1, 4, 3]
    :param polys: list
    :return: list
    """

    for i in range(0, len(poly) - 1, 2):
        poly[i], poly[i + 1] = poly[i + 1], poly[i]

    return poly

@threetimes
def flatten_polys(poly):
    """
    Turns geojson polygons into flat lists.
    :param poly: List of three lists; standard geojson polygon or multipolygon format.
    :return: flat list of the polygon co-ordinates.
    """

    flat_poly = [item for sublist in poly for item in sublist]

    return flat_poly

poly = flatten_polys(poly)
poly = swap_pairs(poly)
polys_formatted = [str(x) + ',' + str(y) + ':' for x, y in zip(poly[0::2], poly[1::2])]
polys_formatted[-1] = polys_formatted[-1].replace(':', '')
poly_as_string = ''.join(x for x in polys_formatted)
```

The problem however is that sometimes the co-ordinates have a different number of sublists rather than three as in the example here, i.e. they look like this (again truncated for brevity's sake):

```
[[[-0.109373710729991, 51.42315755917108], [-0.105987341539958, 51.422576811743276], [-0.096906133161734, 51.422667109533435], [-0.094346733695295, 51.422818864663064], [-0.092734433338077, 51.42253994327862], [-0.088190383828824, 51.419927269261336], [-0.086425687184976, 51.419305849976176], [-0.082346001337163, 51.419771533877956], [-0.078548643992427, 51.41984782473602], [-0.080993694631571, 51.417101046706534], [-0.080475514860821, 51.415566497757084]]]
```

So what I think I need is a function to flatten nested sublists that repeats itself n times until it can no longer execute without an error...

I'll be very grateful for any assistance...

Comment: This isn't a valid syntax: `-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,`. Is that supposed to be a string?

Comment: @Mark Meyer sorry it is a string. My bad.

Comment: @osint_alex FWIW, no one (*cough* except me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63092618/2847946) is getting your output right.

Comment: @Mark Moretto haha going through answers now! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use a recursive function:

```
lst = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]

cor = []

def func(lst):
    for a in lst:
        if isinstance(a,list):
            if not any(isinstance(i, list) for i in a):
                cor.append(f"{a[1]},{a[0]}")
            func(a)
            
func(lst)
print(':'.join(cor))
```

Output:

```
54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:54.722713302903806,-1.24192061729046:54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.7271584144655,-1.270237428346303:54.72608036652354,-1.268210325997062:54.726854573664205,-1.267390512992676
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

```
coordinate_list = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]
```

*EDIT*: Adjusted the coord_pairs function to capture all sublists.

```
# def flatten(iterable):
#     """Recursive flattening of sublists."""
#     if len(iterable) > 1:
#         res = flatten(iterable[0])
#     else:
#         res = iterable[0]
#     return res


# def coord_pairs(lists):
#     out = ""
#     for item in lists:
#         res = flatten(item)
#         out += ":".join([f"{c[1]},{c[0]}" for c in res])
#     return out


def flatten(iterable):
    """Recursive flattening of sublists."""
    if len(iterable) > 1:
        return flatten(iterable[0])
    else:
        return iterable[0]
    return res


def coord_pairs(lists):
    out = ""
    if len(lists) > 1:
        for item in lists:
            res = flatten(item)
            out += ":".join([f"{c[1]},{c[0]}" for c in res])
    else:
        res = flatten(lists)
        out += ":".join([f"{c[1]},{c[0]}" for c in res])
    return out

# Call function to test output.
coord_pairs(coordinate_list)
```

Output:

```
'54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:54.722713302903806,-1.24192061729046:54.722452909315834,-1.24195652631595854.7271584144655,-1.270237428346303:54.72608036652354,-1.268210325997062:54.726854573664205,-1.267390512992676'
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yeah, I was looking at it again and that function gets one out of two sublists.  I might update it or delete it if OP accepts the other answer posted.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Updated it to get the full set.  Not elegant, by any means, but it seems to work better.  I don't know if you meant 'messes up the order' by having the second coordinate first, but OP's post has `54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:...` as the desired output.

Comment: May have been mistaken with the order, sorry about that. It doesn't seem like this should have a ':' in `1.24195652631595854.7271584144655`

Comment: It's a weird order, for sure.  Your comment helped me correct my post, though, so I appreciate it.  Cheers!

Comment: Hey Mark, that one works for the list in my post however it throws this error for different coordinate lists:

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

The structure of those lists look like this:

`[[[0.35734960034587, 51.691419401103474], [0.360525134769747, 51.69037987969592], [0.362860024738573, 51.69170434483416]]]`

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively flatten the lst depending on if each element is a list or not

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst_input = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> flatten = lambda lst: [i for e in lst for i in (chain(reversed(flatten(e)), [':'])  if isinstance(e, list) else [e])]
>>> lst = flatten(lst_input)
>>> lst
[':', 54.722452909315834, -1.241956526315958, ':', 54.72242038994674, -1.242505189342398, ':', 54.722713302903806, -1.24192061729046, ':', 54.722452909315834, -1.241956526315958, ':', ':', ':', 54.7271584144655, -1.270237428346303, ':', 54.72608036652354, -1.268210325997062, ':', 54.726854573664205, -1.267390512992676, ':', ':']
>>> 
>>> ','.join(map(str, lst)).strip(':,').replace(',:,', ':')
'54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:54.722713302903806,-1.24192061729046:54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:::54.7271584144655,-1.270237428346303:54.72608036652354,-1.268210325997062:54.726854573664205,-1.267390512992676'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst_input = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 53.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 52.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]

# look inside the current list, if the next element is also a list flatten the current list
while type(next(iter(lst_input))).__name__ == "list":
    lst_input = [item for sublist in lst_input for item in sublist]

# combine the elements of the fully flattened list as string, keep order
string_output = ":".join([", ".join([str(lst_input[j]),str(lst_input[j-1])]) for j in range(1,len(lst_input))])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This doesn't give me quite the right formatting though in the output and it produces a very long output, so I think it is joining the list to itself too many times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should flat it all the way up to the last list:

```
origx = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]
print(origx)

def flat(x):
    if type(x[0][0]) is list:
        x=[ i for xl in x for i in xl ]
        return flat(x)
    else: 
         return x

def reformat(x):
    s = ""
    for pair in x:
        s=s+str(pair[1])+","+str(pair[0])+":"
    return s[:-1]   


print(reformat(flat(origx)))
```

output

```
54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:54.722713302903806,-1.24192061729046:54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.7271584144655,-1.270237428346303:54.72608036652354,-1.268210325997062:54.726854573664205,-1.267390512992676
```

Comment: Sorry this isn't working for me! 

Still getting sublists left in my output...

Comment: I forgot to reformat it. It is an interesting problem though.

Answer (score 0):

OK got another answer that works for this too in addition to the one from @Prem Anand !

This isn't my code, it's from an answer from a realpython.com user -

```
def flatten(bad):
    good  = []
    while bad:
        e = bad.pop()
        if isinstance(e, list):
            bad.extend(e)
        else:
            good.append(e)
    return good[::-1]
    

poly = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]
poly = flatten(poly)
polys_formatted = [str(x) + ',' + str(y) + ':' for x, y in zip(poly[1::2], poly[0::2])]
poly_as_string = ''.join(x for x in polys_formatted)[:-1]
    
print(poly_as_string)
```

The output I got for this on all the different coordinates I tried for input was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Just for contrast, here's an aproach that doesn't try to walk the data structure at all.  It immediately converts it to a string and then tries to "clean up" the string to appear as you desire:

```
POST_TRANSLATIONS = str.maketrans({'[': None, ']': None})

def flatten_polys(polygons):
    array = []

    for coordinates in str(polygons).split('], ['):
        array.append(','.join(reversed(coordinates.split(', '))))

    return ':'.join(array).translate(POST_TRANSLATIONS)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #  Run some tests

    poly_1 = [[[[-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834], [-1.242505189342398, 54.72242038994674], [-1.24192061729046, 54.722713302903806], [-1.241956526315958, 54.722452909315834]]], [[[-1.270237428346303, 54.7271584144655], [-1.268210325997062, 54.72608036652354], [-1.267390512992676, 54.726854573664205]]]]

    print(flatten_polys(poly_1))

    print()

    poly_2 = [[[-0.109373710729991, 51.42315755917108], [-0.105987341539958, 51.422576811743276], [-0.096906133161734, 51.422667109533435], [-0.094346733695295, 51.422818864663064], [-0.092734433338077, 51.42253994327862], [-0.088190383828824, 51.419927269261336], [-0.086425687184976, 51.419305849976176], [-0.082346001337163, 51.419771533877956], [-0.078548643992427, 51.41984782473602], [-0.080993694631571, 51.417101046706534], [-0.080475514860821, 51.415566497757084]]]

    print(flatten_polys(poly_2))

    print()

    poly_3 = [[[0.35734960034587, 51.691419401103474], [0.360525134769747, 51.69037987969592], [0.362860024738573, 51.69170434483416]]]

    print(flatten_polys(poly_3))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.72242038994674,-1.242505189342398:54.722713302903806,-1.24192061729046:54.722452909315834,-1.241956526315958:54.7271584144655,-1.270237428346303:54.72608036652354,-1.268210325997062:54.726854573664205,-1.267390512992676

51.42315755917108,-0.109373710729991:51.422576811743276,-0.105987341539958:51.422667109533435,-0.096906133161734:51.422818864663064,-0.094346733695295:51.42253994327862,-0.092734433338077:51.419927269261336,-0.088190383828824:51.419305849976176,-0.086425687184976:51.419771533877956,-0.082346001337163:51.41984782473602,-0.078548643992427:51.417101046706534,-0.080993694631571:51.415566497757084,-0.080475514860821

51.691419401103474,0.35734960034587:51.69037987969592,0.360525134769747:51.69170434483416,0.362860024738573
>
```